Cloned Admin Profile, but users still can't see quick actions?
I'm working on a very simple sales cloud org with PersonAccount model (no managed packages, and only a single Apex Class with a single method). I have 4 quick action buttons on a custom object record page (Program__c). All quick actions are connected to auto-launched screen flows. 2 show up for all users, and 2 only show up for Admins. All sharing settings are set to public read/write (small org with less than 10 users), but I added an additional sharing rule to share all records with all users as a backup.
I even cloned the admin profile and re-assigned it to the users who previously could NOT see the 2 quick actions, AND THEY STILL CAN'T SEE THE QUICK ACTIONS. I've gone through every single line in both profiles and they are exactly the same with the exception of IsCustomProfile == true/false and the profile name. In particular, both profiles have:

full CRUD access to all SObjects involved in all quick actions
full R/W Field-Level Security to all fields on all SObjects involved in all quick actions
Record type and page layout assignments are identical

I'm totally stuck. What on earth could be the issue here if not page layout assignments, record type assignments, SOjbect access, FLS access, or record sharing? (It's not a flow access problem as the standard users can see the other two quick actions are also connected to flows).

How are you controlling the access to quick action buttons? For example, how are you controlling the fact admin can see all 4 quick actions and non-admin users to only see 2?

Are you using Dynamic Actions on the Program page?

The quick actions are assigned to the Page Layouts, but the record pages are dynamic flexiPages. There is no conditional rendering of the quick action buttons on the record pages.
